# react reducer toolkit dispatch not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I wrote profile page I want to get profile datas from api but my dispatch not working, in getProfileDetails function dispatch not working.

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "../components/axios";
import urls from "../components/Urls";
import authHeader from "../components/authHeader";

const profileSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'profile',
    initialState: {
        profileDetails: [],
    },
    reducers: {
        setProfileDetails: (state, action) => {
            state.profileDetails = action.payload;
            //return { profileDetails: action.payload };
        },
    }
});

export const getProfileDetails = (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(urls.user_details, { headers: authHeader() }).then((response) => {
        dispatch(setProfileDetails(response.data.results[0]));
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

export const { setProfileDetails } = profileSlice.actions;
export default profileSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

A reducer must always return a new object, so your commented version was actually better. Better still would be something like this:

```js
const profileSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'profile',
  initialState: {
    profileDetails: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setProfileDetails: (state, action) => ({ ...state, profileDetails: action.payload }),
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but returned empty array and I use that slice in profile page in useEffect. import {getProfileDetails} from "../../features/profileSlice"; useEffect(() => { getProfileDetails(dispatch); }, []); –

Comment: I use import {getProfileDetails} from "../../features/profileSlice"; const profileDetails = useSelector(state => state.profileSlice.profileDetails); is there any not correct calling this line ?

Comment: I think my problem is in this line dispatch(setProfileDetails(response.data.results[0])); dispatch not connect to setProfileDetails ?